# How To Access A Field From A Static Method Java

Tags: java

So let's say I have this code for a class:

```
public class A {

    static int myInt;

    static void setMyInt(int myInt) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

I don't know why you would have a setter in a static method, but this is just an example. Normally for a non-static situation, I would do something like this:

```
public class A {

    int myInt;

    void setMyInt(int myInt) {
        this.myInt = myInt;
    }

}
```

Using `this` accesses the field instead of the parameter. However, in the static method, I can't access `this` since it is a non-static field. How do I go about accessing the field from a static method?

Comment: You can access a static field from a static method without `this`. You cannot access a non-static field from a static method, unless you first create an instance and access that instance's field. You can return the instance from the static method, so that the caller can see the set instance field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is `static`, there is no `this`. Option 1: Give the parameter another name. Option 2: Use the class name to specify which `myInt`. Like,

```
static int myInt;
static void setMyInt(int myInt) {
    A.myInt = myInt;
}
```

**or**

```
static int myInt;
static void setMyInt(int myOtherInt) {
    myInt = myOtherInt; // A.myInt = myOtherInt; would also work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you define static property you no need create instance from your class .
for **non-static** property and **encapsulation** using setter for each field is better
and by **this** keyword can give value to Intended property.

```
   int myInt;
      void setMyInt(int myInt) {
        this.myInt = myInt;
    }
```

for **static** property no need setter

```
   static int myInt;
      static void setMyInt(int myInt) {
        (your class name).myInt = myInt;
    }
```